# How to crop text after pattern in bash

Tags: bash, sed

If the text is

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
====
dddd
```

I want `dddd` as the result

If the text is

```
aaaa
====
bbbb
cccc
dddd
```

I want

```
bbbb
cccc
dddd
```

as the result.

I'm trying something like `awk '{print $1}' | sed '/.*\n=*$/d'` but it seems like sed can only delete a line.

Comment: How about: `sed -n '/^=/,${/^=/!p}' input_file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like

```
n=$(grep -n "^=*$" $1 | awk -F: '{print $1}')
let n+=1
tail +$n $1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can indicate a range of lines, e.g. from line 1 to the line containing the pattern:

```
sed '1,/====/d'
```

Comment: It will break if the `===` line appears in the 1st line. With `GNU sed` we can say `sed '0,/====/d'`.

Comment: So first of all, I have to get which line is the delimiter line?